# How to resize of Delete button of UITableView in delete editting mode?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I chage size of cell of a table to 20 but Delete button don't change. So, how to resize this button is this case?

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: maybe takes all subviews of cell or make custom cell

Comment: As a suggestion, don't resize your table view rows this small.  20-pixel-high rows will be extremely hard to tap on with a finger.  Apple recommends that no element on the screen have a touchable area of less than 44 x 44 pixels.  Besides, the text on the Delete view will be unreadable if the button is only 20 pixels tall.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set **autoresizesSubviews** property of the **UITableViewCell** class?